# Adding namespace in JavaScript cause Unexpected token '.' error

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I follow the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/881556/2704265 to add a namespace, as below:

```js
var theme1 = {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    });
};
```

However, after that, I will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'` which point to the '.' after 'document', why?

Comment: Object literals require key-value pairs. `document.addEventListener(...` is not a key-value pair.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Thank you. Why removing the namespace will solve the issue?

Comment: When you type `theme1 = { document`. The next thing the parser is looking for is: another part of the identifier (i.e., `document1`); a whitespace character, followed by one of the remaining items (i.e., `document `); a colon (i.e., `document:`); a comma, if the identifier refers to a variable already defined (i.e., `document,`), an open parenthesis (i.e., `document(`). There are other symbols that can be used but generally, with a open curly brace, some whitespace and the identifier `document`, that's about the only valid things you can put.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the example given in the answer provided you have the following:

```js
var yourNamespace = {

    foo: function() {
    },

    bar: function() {
    }
};

...

yourNamespace.foo();
```

The code you gave would need to look something more like this:

```js
var themeNamespace = {
   domLoader: function() {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    });
   },
}
```

Then run using `themeNamespace.domLoader();`